# Missing development tools when building colorls

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, native

When I try to build `colorls` it fails and complains about missing development tools. I have installed all needed packages - at least all I know that are required. I don't know which development tools are missing and which packages I need to install.

```
❯ sudo gem install colorls
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing colorls:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/clocale-0.0.4/ext/clocale
/usr/bin/ruby3.0 -I /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby -r ./siteconf20230421-86160-l0scrv.rb extconf.rb
checking for locale.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)3.0
    --with-locale-dir
    --without-locale-dir
    --with-locale-include
    --without-locale-include=${locale-dir}/include
    --with-locale-lib
    --without-locale-lib=${locale-dir}/lib
/usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:471:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:613:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1124:in `block in have_header'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:971:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:970:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/3.0.0/mkmf.rb:1123:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/clocale-0.0.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/gems/clocale-0.0.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/clocale-0.0.4/gem_make.out
```

Okay, it complains missing libraries or header files. As suggested I check the log file:

```
❯ bat /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/clocale-0.0.4/mkmf.log
───────┬────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       │ File: /var/lib/gems/3.0.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.0.0/clocale-0.0.4/mkmf.log
───────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby-3.0.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-3.0.0/ruby/bac
       │ kward -I/usr/include/ruby-3.0.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/ruby3.0-p
       │ 8XSIY/ruby3.0-3.0.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/li
       │ b/x86_64-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector-strong -rdynamic -Wl,
       │ -export-dynamic     -lruby-3.0  -lm   -lc"
   2   │ collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   3   │ checked program was:
   4   │ /* begin */
   5   │ 1: #include "ruby.h"
   6   │ 2: 
   7   │ 3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
   8   │ 4: {
   9   │ 5:   return !!argv[argc];
  10   │ 6: }
  11   │ /* end */
  12   │ 
───────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I am using Linux Mint 21.1 Vera (latest LTS version) based on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with kernel 5.15.0-56-generic and have the following packages installed: `gcc make ubuntu-dev-tools ruby ruby-dev ruby-colorize`

As far as I know that should be enough to build `colorls`. But it looks like I'm still missing something and I can't figure out, what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing [build-essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/build-essential). You can read more at [What is build-essential Ubuntu?](https://linuxhint.com/install-build-essential-ubuntu/)

Install it with:

```bash
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Unrelated to your question, do not use `sudo gem install ...` unless running `gem install ...` fails with an error telling you that it *must* be run with `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But `build-essential` is already installed. In the case of `colorls` it needs `sudo`.